# How do I host Microsoft Sql server in Amazon aws server??

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, model-view-controller, hyperlink

I have created a simple  windows form application with database. 
I want to use the exe file of my application in different places but I want to store all the data into a centralized database.. Is this possible??

Comment: look into azure SQL database https://azure.microsoft.com/ko-kr/services/sql-database/?&wt.mc_id=AID627445_SEM_ please read documentations first before you ask questions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will just need to make sure each "node" of your application has the proper login credentials to the server and Database. I suggest adding them as a config file and not hard coding them into the program.